# What is the best mobile data solution for a short trip in the US?

Tags: usa, data-plans, vacations

I'm going on a vacation to the US next month for 2 weeks.

Instead of paying roaming fees, I'd like to buy a new SIM card with a prepaid amount from a local store/carrier. I don't think wifi networks will suffice for my needs.

Is that an easily achievable solution for short-term vacationers? Also, what is the deal with US mobile networks not using the GSM standard?

Comment: Welcome to TSE.  There are many question about prepaid plans in the US.  Also, I am not sure where you've heard that US has no GSM carriers.

Comment: *"Is that an easily achievable solution for short-term vacationers?"*  **No.**

Comment: If you are from the UK you can use the Three sim in the US as it's a [Feel At Home](http://www.three.co.uk/Discover/Phones/Feel_At_Home) destination.

Comment: Of the major 4 networks, AT&T and T-Mobile operate GSM networks (specifically 3G UMTS/HSDPA networks). Each of them also are the backing network for a variety of MVNOs. Sprint and Verizon operate CDMA networks.  All the major carriers also operate LTE on different bands.